# Exception when using nlohmann json. (array of object)

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am writing code using the [nlohmann json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and I have gotten the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
  what():  [json.exception.type_error.311] cannot use emplace_back() with object
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now, I am going to detail what my code did but before I took a view of the [following page](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/json_transport/html/classnlohmann_1_1detail_1_1type__error.html) and I noticed that error 311 is not what it says above. Instead

```
json.exception.type_error.311   cannot use emplace_back() with string   The emplace_back() member function can only be executed for certain JSON types.
```

Anyway, my code was like this

```
#include "common/nlohmann/json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;
using ordered_json = nlohmann::ordered_json;

void AClass::do_something(){
  std::ofstream o_file(output_file);
  ordered_json json_result;
  ordered_json json_;
  json_result["output"]=json::array();

  // get some "result" ( a struct)
  json_=getJsonFromResult(result);
  json_result.emplace_back(json_); //<--HERE the error!

  o_file<<json_result.dump();
  o_file.close();
}

ordered_json AClass::getJsonFromResult(TheResult& result){
   ordered_json json_;
   json_["blabla"]="blabla";
   return json_;
}
```

However if I modify in order to emplace back the object *inside* the function, no error or exception happens

```
void AClass::do_something(){
  std::ofstream o_file(output_file);
  ordered_json json_result;
  ordered_json json_;
  json_result["output"]=json::array();

  // get some "result" ( a struct)
  json_=getJsonFromResult(result);
  //json_result.emplace_back(json_); //<--Lets eliminate this!

  o_file<<json_result.dump();
  o_file.close();
}

ordered_json AClass::getJsonFromResult(TheResult& result){
   ordered_json json_;
   json_["blabla"]="blabla";
   json_result["output".emplace_back(json_); //THIS WORKS!!
   return json_;
}
```

`json_result` is a member variable of `AClass`

Anyway, why emplace_back works inside the function but not in the other case? Is it because it is the output of a function?

Comment: Err .. Shouldn't your first example call `json_result["output"].emplace_back(json_)` instead? A few lines above you make `json_result["output"]` an array. That is also what your other example shows.

Comment: @Botje Yes! Thank you! I did not see that.